# calculating a statistically significant difference in means between groups

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, categorical-data, ranking

A large number of subjects repeatedly pass or fail a test. The test frequency is irregular and randomized per user.

Organize this data set in groups by the average test frequency being once per week (or more), once per month, once per quarter, or once per year.

For each group, we want to understand how much the fail rate improved (lowered):

1. calculate the percentage of fails for the first test (number of fails for first test/number of users in group) as pff
2. calculate the percentage of fails for all recorded tests (total number fails over lifetime/total number of tests over time) as ltf
3. calculate the improvement rate as (pff-ltf)/pff

I would like to compare the improvement rate between groups. How would I calculate confidence intervals and the statistical significance of any difference between groups?

Comment: Take a look at repeated measures, in particular hierarchical modeling for repeated measures, I believe.